# Persistence a child object with existing parent one

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

Assume there are two entities with ManyToOne relation:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    private long code;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    public long getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public viod setCode(long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    // additional setters and getters
}

@Entity
public class B {
    private long code;
    private A a;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    public long getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public viod setCode(long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }   

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="acode", nullable=false)   
    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a
    }

    // additional setters and getters   
}
```

As part of the business flow I have code value of the existing A object and I need to insert new B object and relate it to the existing A.
This code works fine:

```
// inject em
A a = em.find(A.class, code);
B b = new B();
b.setA(a);
em.persist(b);
```

My problem is with "A a = em.find(A.class, code)" line. This looks like for me as a redundant query because the B table contains a foreign key (acode).
In order to improve performance I tried to create A object with an existing code value:

```
A a = new A();
a.setCode(code);
B b = new B();
b.setA(a);
em.persist(b);
```

but it doesn't work.
Is there any way to avoid unnecessary query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special `getReference()` method that can be used instead of `find()` in exactly this scenario. It creates a proxy object with the specified id without issuing queires. Existence of `A` with that id is checked by foreign key constraint at the database side when saving `B`.

```
A a = em.getReference(A.class, code);
B b = new B();
b.setA(a);
em.persist(b);
```